# ios 7 - Async Image Download UITableView For Image with Unknown Dimension

Tags: ios, image, uitableview, asynchronous, afnetworking

I am using XCode 6.3.1 targeting iOS 7.

I am using `AFNetworking`'s `UIImageView` category to download images with an unknown dimension to `UITableViewCell`'s. Here is a sample image:

[image]

The issue I am having is that since the dimensions of the image is unknown, I just use a placeholder image. If the placeholder image has the exact same dimensions, then there is no issue. However, if the dimensions are different, there are issues with spacing in the cell.

If the image is smaller than there will be too much spacing. Here is an example:

[image]

I don't know how to refresh the cell after I finish downloading the image so that the spacing is per my `Auto Layout Constraints`.

If I scroll away from the cell and scroll back, the spacing is fine.

Here is some sample code for the downloading of the image

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        // Temp
    static NSString *Cell = @"CustomListCell";
    CustomListCell *cell = (CustomListCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cell];
    CustomListRow *customListRow = self.customList.rows[indexPath.row];

    // Reset the cell
    cell.headerImageView.image = nil;
    cell.titleLabel.text = @"";

    // Download the image, placeholder image is necessary
    NSString *topImageURL = @"sample_image";
    __weak __typeof(cell)weakCell = cell;
    if ([topImageURL isEqualToString:@""] || [topImageURL isEqualToString:@"false"])
    {
        // Do nothing
    } else {
        [cell.headerImageView setImageWithName:topImageURL afterManipulation:^UIImage *(UIImage *image) {
            // Manipulation
            UIImage *newImage = [UIImage expandImage:image toWidth:Constants.screenWidth - 16];

//            CustomListCell *updateCell = (CustomListCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//            if (updateCell)
//                updateCell.headerImageView.image = newImage;
            return newImage;
        } placeholderImage:[UIImage expandImage:Constants.placeholderImage toWidth:Constants.screenWidth - 26]];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

`setImageWithName:afterManipulation:placeholderImage:` is a method I made to wrap around `AFNetworking`'s `setImageWithURL`.... It first checks of the image exists locally before checking two different URL's (absolute and base_url + relative) if the image exists there.

I put the manipulation block in there so that I could call a `UIImage` category method I created that will scale the image to fit the width of the `UITableView` (so the only dynamic part is the height).

Here is a list of things I have tried:

- Reloading the particular cell
- reloading the entire table
- `[self.tableView beginUpdates] + [self.tableView endUpdates];`
- Calling `[cell setNeedsLayout]`, or `[cell setNeedsDiplay];`

`setNeedsLayout` and `setNeedsDisplay` didn't do anything once I finished loading the image (I placed it in the afterManipulation block which is called before the image is assigned, and I have also tried placing it after the image is assigned).

Reloading the cell, the table, or beginUpdates causes some really weird behavior to occur. The cells start getting mixed together and some cells have the same picture (which shouldn't happen). I'm not sure what is happening, but my guess is that reloading the cell causes image to download again (or pull it from the cache) which doesn't finish until after another cell is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about playing with the `contentMode` property of the image view?

> A flag used to determine how a view lays out its content when its bounds change.

An issue that I observed while looking at your implementation is that you might get wrong images in the cells. I see you take the cell as a reference when downloading the image. This is wrong, and here is why:

Table view cells get reused so when you scroll the cells that get off screen will be used again to display the information for other rows. By taking a reference to the cell and not the indexpath, if your download takes time, when the completion block is called, that cell may be displaying information for a different row and thus, the image you apply on it may not be the right one.

You should have a look at Apple's example of how to keep consistency while downloading images for every table view cell: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: I believe that AFNetworking's UIImageView should take care of that. If a new request is called, it should cancel the old request and replace it with the new request. In their sample code they don't have any reference to the indexpath (or something other than the cell)